# Azure VM instance IP firewall

Tags: security, firewall, virtual-machines, azure, cloud

I assigned an instance-level IP address to my Azure VM. I then configured the SSH "endpoint" from the Azure portal and defined a deny-all policy.

However, this policy seems to only affect the cloud service VIP, and not the instance-level IP which is completely open to the internet. I am now seeing Chinese hackers trying to brute force the system on this IP.

How can I apply my deny-all policy to the instance-level IP?

[image: Azure portal deny-all policy for SSH]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an endpoint acl take a look at a Network Security Group, applied to either the Vm or the vnet check https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/network-security-groups/ and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scom_2012_upgrade_process__lessons_learned_during_my_upgrade_process/archive/2015/01/18/controlling-traffic-between-subnets-within-a-vnet-managing-vms-in-azure-iaas-with-azure-powershell-part-2.aspx and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-ps/

Comment: Read this article at the bottom https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/ ... Also since last week NSG's for the classic model were added to the Portal (IBIZA)

Comment: I just implemented an NSG and associated it with the VM, added a deny-all policy for SSH, but again, it has zero effect on the instance-level IP :(

Comment: Did you remove the acl too? They can not co-exist. While at it enable security center to see what else is going on. When enabling acl and msg you need to enforce update vm too btw

Comment: Removed all ACL endpoints, stopped/deallocated the VM, restarted it, tried connecting to the new PIP, still works, despite my NSG having the deny-all policy.

Answer (score 1):

If you have assigned Instance Level Public IP Address(ILPIP or earlier known as PIP) to your instance then you won't be able to restrict the inbound traffic unless you configure that particular instance's OS level firewall or create NSG because the sole purpose of ILPIP is to receive traffic from external sources on dynamic ports meaning anyone can send data to your ILPIP without even specifying ports.

So summarizing, if you want to receive traffic from external sources on any port then assign your instance an ILPIP and configure its OS level firewall or create NSG accordingly else if you don't want any external traffic coming to your instance directly at dynamic ports at all then remove the ILPIP.

Comment: By firewall, do you mean from the portal or the OS-level firewall (i.e. Windows Firewall, or firewalld). Keep in mind that this is a classic deployment, not ARM.

Comment: Have edited my answer. I meant OS level firewall only because from the portal you can only control Azure's Internal Load Balancer's ports.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I hope you're not right because that would be a pretty silly oversight on Microsoft's part to not give you a way to restrict access from the portal. Also, someone on the MSDN blogs has told me NSG's should affect the ILPIP. I'll do some more testing and follow up.

Comment: Just checked your screenshot, instead of providing 22 in public port can you pls put * there and try?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't patient enough initially but it seems that if I create the NSG, apply it to a VM, and wait about 5 minutes, it then finally takes effect and blocks out all traffic including to the ILPIP.